# Deserialize causes InvalidOperationException when loading on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-serialization

I have a class that is able to serialize and deserialize with ease after my WPF application has loaded. I am now trying to add in the ability to load a project on startup when passing in the project file. Unfortunately, it is throwing an InvalidOperationException stating:

`There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <WeightingParametersBit xmlns=''> was not expected.`

The `WeightingParametersBit` is the type of a member of the class I am trying to serialize. It is basically just a container for a Dictionary. The odd thing is, the file does not contain a tag for `<WeightingParametersBit xmlns=....` anywhere in the file. Once this exception is thrown and the application starts. If I click the load button and select the same project file, it loads up just fine.

Here is the class I am trying to serialize (small container class):

```
public class WeightSettings
{
    public double UserScoreSlagging;
    public double UserScoreFouling;
    public WeightMode BitWeightMode = WeightMode.Manual;
    public WeightMode LigWeightMode = WeightMode.Manual;
    public WeightingParametersBit BitWeights = new WeightingParametersBit();
    public WeightingParametersLig LigWeights = new WeightingParametersLig();
}
```

And here is the xml it generates (trimmed down for viewing purposes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WeightSettings>
    <UserScoreSlagging>0</UserScoreSlagging>
    <UserScoreFouling>0</UserScoreFouling>
    <BitWeightMode>Manual</BitWeightMode>
    <LigWeightMode>Manual</LigWeightMode>
    <BitWeights>
        <bituminous>
            ...
        </bituminous>
    </BitWeights>
    <LigWeights>
        <lignitic>
          ...
        </lignitic>
    </LigWeights>
</WeightSettings>
```

My generic serialize code:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(this T source, TextWriter writer)
{
    // Don't serialize a null object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Trying to serialize null object.", "source");
    }

    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    s.Serialize(writer, source);
    writer.WriteLine();
}
```

And deserialize code:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this T source, TextReader reader)
{
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    source = (T)s.Deserialize(reader);
    return source;
}
```

The call to deserialize is from a property called `WeightSettings` (of type `WeightSettings`) which is not null:

`WeightSettings = WeightSettings.Deserialize(sr);`

How can I fix this behavior? Perhaps more importantly: why do I see this behavior only on the Window Loaded event?

Comment: Does a namespace need to be defined anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually trying to load the same file?

Comment: @brumScouse not that I'm aware. 
@Jon Skeet the execution is the same during the load event and after; as far as I can tell, it is the same file

Comment: I have run to simular issues with the load event. I am not sure what is causing the issue, I usualy kick off a timer right after the InitializeComponent statement in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jon Skeet was on the right track. I was not changing the current working directory until after my application was fully loaded, so it could not find the file.

Very cryptic exception when it simply should have been `FileNotFoundException`